# Configuração de server asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, servidor, asp

boa tarde.
Estou me aventurando em um server asp, só que estou perdido em sua configuração.
Como dev php, coloquei um index.php em um server asp esperando que ele funcionasse, entretanto não funcionou.
Procurando mais sobre, percebi que eu deveria configurar o web.config, então procurando na net, configurei da seguinte maneira.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear />
<add value="default2.asp" />
<add value="default.asp" />
<add value="index.asp" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Mas obtenho o seguinte erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obtive esse erro, tanto na raiz, quanto em uma subpasta.
Se eu excluo o web-config, ele não chamada nenhum arquivo.
Podem me dar um help com essa configuração?

(Estou exportando um servidor, ele funcionava perfeitamente no server antigo, porém o webconfig de lá, não ficava na pasta que eu tenho acesso)

Comment: Poderia colar o erro ao invés da imagem?

Comment: claro, erro que na imagem está em "azul"

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: Descrição do erro em more information

This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

Comment: Tem certeza que PHP funciona em server ASP sem instalar também um interpretador PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei chegando a conclusão que ambos os erros, de configuração e não reconhecimento de default/index era por causa que o servidor não roda asp clássico (minha atual aplicação), apenas asp.net.